# Rmarkdown tabu.sty error in PDF output with libraries

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, libraries

Hello R community i'm trying to knit a pdf document, but get an error and cannot find the right answer in any forum. I'm using the latest R(4.1) and Rstudio(1.4). I have MiKTeX installed but I can not get a pdf to write unless I changed the global setting in R to write from tiny tex.

I have isolated the problem in the script. If I try to knit the document without loading any libraries, the document WILL knit. If I try to knit with libraries, then I throw a tabu.sty error. The problem here is I need the libraries for tables, graphs, etc.

````
! LaTeX Error: File `tabu.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Chapter0.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Chapter0.log for more info.
Execution halted```
````

Comment: Getting this error is actually a good thing. The tabu package is more or less completely broken and causes way more problems than it solves. Don't use it unless you are threatened with torture.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] to reproduce the error?

Comment: I was finally able to fix the issue, but it took a day or two. Troubleshooting took on so many different avenues I can't give a good answer that fixed it. Updating all the files, reloading the packages directly from github developer, changing settings in the general options, etc.